# How to coax `missingno` nullity plot to show only selected columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

The nullity plot, generated with [missingno](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno), of my data looks like this:

[image]

but I don't need to display the first 10 columns (`no` to `uv_bottom`). Is there any way to get `missingno` to show only select columns, aside from manually cropping the image?

The [advanced configuration](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) described in the docs doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a data frame df, with the above data, then to display from 11 column, you can use the below code

ax = missingno.matrix(df[list(df)[10:]])